# jqGrid vs. <delete> button: I can't pass a parameter

Tags: parameters, asp-classic, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid to load data from MS Sql Server using asp classic. 
I correctly visualize all my record and by using #pager can `add` and `edit` them. 
I cannot use `delete` because when I click on that button and the pop-up opens,  I can't pass parameter (`id_city`): this is my big problem. It's not displaying any error message.

I try to post some code (I don't know how to format it):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list").jqGrid({ 
        url:'loadxml.asp', //this execute a stored procedure and create a xml document 
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames:["id_city","name_city"], 
        colModel :[ 
            {name:'id_city', index:'id_city',editable:true, width:100,reloadAfterSubmit: true}, 
            {name:'name_city', editable:true,reloadAfterSubmit: true,index:'name_city',width:300, reloadAfterSubmit: true,closeAfterAdd:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true}
        ], 
        height:600, 
        rowNum:50,
        pager : '#pager',
        viewrecords: false, 
        imgpath: 'css/ui-lightness/images',
        loadonce: false, 
        xmlReader: { 
            root : "NewDataSet", 
            row: "Table", 
            repeatitems: false, 
            id: "id_city" 
        },
        sortorder: "name_city",
        caption:'summary',
        editurl:"edit.asp" // here there is a select case... I can't pass id_city to delete
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:false,refresh:false});
    $('#pager_center').empty(); // workaround to see only <edit>,<add>,<delete> buttons         
});
```

Comment: Is there a field called `id_city` in your html form? Try writing out the SQL string after constructing it: do you get a valid SQL statement? Do you have delete permissions on the SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line before **colModel**.

```
prmNames: {id: "id_city"},
```